# "Illegal string offset" when working with foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm getting the "Warning: Illegal string offset" error when trying to extract data from an array I have converted from JSON.

Now I gather this happens when the index you are using does not exist, which puzzles me because it does exist and works fine when I wish to access the array value directly.

My JSON is decoded into the array using the code `$clean = json_decode($json_output, true);` and if I use `echo $clean['text']` the string value of 'text' is displayed fine.

However when I attempt this piece of code I get the error:

```
foreach ($clean as $key => $list){
$output .= $list['text'];}
```

I have a feeling I am making a silly mistake somewhere!

Comment: Please Check The structure of array With `print_r($clean)`;

Answer (score 1):

With `$list['text']` you are actually accessing the value of `$clean['text']`, which is apparently the string `"text"`. Only, you're accessing it as if it were an associative array - actually exactly the same one as `$clean`. Try this:

```
foreach ($clean as $key => $list)
{
    if ($key === 'text')
    {// only echo for $clean['text']
        echo 'array clean, key: '.$key.' => '.$list."\n";
        continue;//next
    }
    echo $key.' => '.$list."\n";//shows all other key-value pairs
}
```

That should clear things up for you: `$key` will hold all keys that `$clean` holds, including `text`, `$list` will be assigned the value referenced by that key. It's as simple as that, really

Comment: Note that your answer is wrong! if `$clean` would be a string, then there would be a different error message: `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() `

Comment: @hek2mgl: I'm not saying `$clean` is a string, that's an associative array, `$list` is a string that the OP is accessing as if it were `$clean`... I was trying to be concise, but I'll edit, because I see why you might think I meant otherwise.

Comment: @hek2mgl: Sorry, but there's no point in adding _"thanks hek2mgl for pointing out that my original answer was confusing"_. In essence, both say the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that `$list` is a string rather than an array. Therefore `$list['text']` fails. `var_dump($list);` inside the loop will help.

Note that `var_dump()` will be always your friend if you encounter such problems.